# Grab Facebook Video Thumbnail using api or id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What i'm trying to do is let a user copy either the embed or url provided by Facebook for a specific video.

when user paste the url or embed code i'll  then  run some regex expression to grab the thumbnail and title then save those properties to my database.

then when the page refreshes after saving the post , a custom player will appear, the actually Facebook video player won't appear until someone clicks play.

Im doing this so that my page loads quickly , and isn't slowed down by the actual player's js, that is until the user actually clicks play.

I already know how to do all this, except, I don't know how to grab the thumbnail for the Facebook video player.

unlike most sites , Facebook doesnt provide the thumbnail in og:image meta tag.

so how can i grab the thumbnail url to save to my database?

Answer (score 0):

i created a php function to answer your question without you having to go through reading the boring documentation about facebook graph. All you will need is just to insert your video link,facebook and youtube, but you can modify to add other sources.
i created a php function to answer your question without you having to go through reading the boring documentation about facebook graph.
All you will need is just to insert your video link,facebook and youtube, but you can modify to add other sources.
simply copy the youtube video link in the addres bar and for for facebook, right click on the video and click on show video url, then copy that.

```
    //get video thumbnail for facebook and youtube
function get_vid_thumbnail($link){
    $thumbnail='';
//check if video link is facebook
    if (strpos($link, 'facebook') !== false) {
        $thumbnail=fb_thumb($link);
        //$thumbnail='fb';
    }
//check if video link is youtube
    if (strpos($link, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
        $thumbnail=youtube_thumb($link);
        //$thumbnail='youtube';
    }
    return $thumbnail;
}


//supporting functions
//get youtube thumbnail
function youtube_thumb($link){
    $new=str_replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','', $link);
    $vv='https://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$new.'/0.jpg';
    return $vv;
}

//clean the facebook link
function fb_video_id($url) {
    //split the url
    $main=parse_url($url);
    //get the pathe and split to get the video id
    $main=$main['path'];
    $main=explode('/',$main);
    $main=$main[3];
    return $main;
}
//get the thumbnail
function fb_thumb($link) {
    $img = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.fb_video_id($link).'/picture';
    return $img;
}

//get video thumbnail for fb and youtube ends

//get embed url for facebook and youtube to be used as video source
function get_vid_embed_url($link){
    $embed_url='sss';
//check if video link is facebook
    if (strpos($link, 'facebook') !== false) {
        # code...
        $embed_url=fb_embed_link($link);
        //$thumbnail='fb';
    }
//check if video link is youtube
    if (strpos($link, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
        # code...
        $embed_url=youtube_embed_link($link);
        //$thumbnail='youtube';
    }
    return $embed_url;
}
//get youtube embed link
function youtube_embed_link($link){
    $new=str_replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=','', $link);
    $link='https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$new;
    return $link;
}
//get facebook embed link
function fb_embed_link($link) {
    $link = 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href='.$link.'&show_text=0&width=560';
    return $link;
}
```